# Understanding this behavior with allocating integer array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know I should be using realloc to grow an array but in a momentary lapse of thought I did it this way. I realize the approach is wrong as I am corrupting the heap by growing it without allocating the array. So I am essentially writing garbage. But when the code is small and nothing else is happening I don't see why this should not work. I get garbage for the first few values

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int **p = NULL;
    int i=0;
    int size = 5;
    int *n = NULL;

    p = malloc(sizeof(int*));

    printf("p = %p \n", p);

    for( i=0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        int *k;
        k = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *k = i;
        p[i] = k;
        printf("%p, %p, val = %d \n", k, p[i], *k);
    }

    printf("Now print the array -- \n");
    for( i=0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        int *k;
        k = p[i];
        printf("value at mem %p == %d \n", p[i], *k);
    }

    printf("now print the next values in p \n");
    for( i=0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        printf("value at %p = %p \n", p+i, *(p+i) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of the code --

```
p = 0x7f8ffbc031c0
0x7f8ffbc031d0, 0x7f8ffbc031d0, val = 0
0x7f8ffbc031e0, 0x7f8ffbc031e0, val = 1
0x7f8ffbc031f0, 0x7f8ffbc031f0, val = 2
0x7f8ffbc03200, 0x7f8ffbc03200, val = 3
0x7f8ffbc03210, 0x7f8ffbc03210, val = 4
Now print the array --
value at mem 0x7f8ffbc031d0 == -71290384
value at mem 0x7f8ffbc031e0 == -71290352
value at mem 0x7f8ffbc031f0 == 2
value at mem 0x7f8ffbc03200 == 3
value at mem 0x7f8ffbc03210 == 4
now print the next values in p
value at 0x7f8ffbc031c0 = 0x7f8ffbc031d0
value at 0x7f8ffbc031c8 = 0x7f8ffbc031e0
value at 0x7f8ffbc031d0 = 0x7f8ffbc031f0
value at 0x7f8ffbc031d8 = 0x7f8ffbc03200
value at 0x7f8ffbc031e0 = 0x7f8ffbc03210
```

I cannot explain why the first two values are garbage even though the memory address pointed to by p and p+1 are what I put there.

Comment: Probably because you corrupted the heap.

Comment: Or more specifically: You'll notice that `p[2]` and `*p[0]` have the same address - the third pointer overwrote the first number. Same for `p[4]` and `*p[1]`.

Comment: `p = malloc(sizeof(int*));` only allocates memory for one `int*` but the later `p[i] = k;` breaks it.

Comment: You say you know you should be using realloc to grow an array but in a momentary lapse of thought you did it this way. You realize the approach is wrong but still want to know why you are writing garbage. Hmm.... answer: write it properly :)

Comment: @immibis -- thanks I did not notice that.  I know its wrong. Just couldnt see what exactly is going wrong. I should have seen that malloc will give me the  next available pointer and should have seen that p[2] would be wrong.

Comment: once you drift into Undefined Behavior land all bets are off. Things might work a bit, a lot, never,....

Comment: " I should have seen that malloc will give me the next available pointer " That no what malloc does. It allocates a block of memory and returns a pointer to it. `malloc(sizeof(int*))` is returning you a pointer to a block of memory big enough to hold a pointer. Almost certainly what you dont want

Comment: @WeatherVane Nothing wrong with wanting to understand why undefined behaviour works a particular way on one platform - it can give you deeper insight into the platform.

Comment: @immibis yes I do see the value as I have remarked in other questions, but many commenters here will say "undefined behaviour (end of)". Even at a job interview. Like with a college interview: they want more than a 2 word answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior. Nevertheless I can explain the result of this program run.

Usually when a memory allocation request is less than the size of the paragraph that is usually equal to 16 bytes then the function `malloc` allocates a chunk of memory exactly equal to the size of paragraph.

So after this statement

```
p = malloc(sizeof(int*));
```

there was allocated 16 bytes at address

```
p = 0x7f8ffbc031c0
```

Thus you can use addresses

`0x7f8ffbc031c0` and `0x7f8ffbc031c8` that belong to the allocated extent.

The first and the second chunks allocated in the loop by the statement

```
k = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

is

```
0x7f8ffbc031d0
0x7f8ffbc031e0
```

In the same loop due to the statement

```
    p[i] = k;
```

there are accesses the memory beyond the allocated extent pointed to by the pointer `p`.

so you have for the expression `p[i]` sequentially

```
0x7f8ffbc031c0   - p[0] 
0x7f8ffbc031c8   - p[1]
0x7f8ffbc031d0   - p[2]  - Oops! the address 0x7f8ffbc031d0 is overwritten
0x7f8ffbc031d8   - p[3]  
0x7f8ffbc031e0   - p[4]  - Oops! the address 0x7f8ffbc031e0 is overwritten!
```

So the first two addresses where the first two integers were stored are overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
p = malloc(sizeof(int*));
```

only allocates a single element to `p`; `p[1]` through `p[4]` don't exist (or, more properly, you don't own the memory corresponding to those elements).  To allocate a `size`-element array of `int *`, that line needs to be

```
p = malloc( size * sizeof *p ); // sizeof *p == sizeof (int *)
```

Also,

```
int *k;
k = malloc(sizeof(int));
*k = i;
p[i] = k;
```

could simply be written as

```
p[i] = malloc( sizeof *p[i] ); // sizeof *p[i] == sizeof (int)
if ( p[i] ) // **always** check the result of a malloc, calloc, or realloc call!
  *p[i] = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. You declare `p` as single pointer to pointer, but then you use it as an array of `size` items. To do that you must allocate the array of required size. Your current `p = malloc(sizeof(int*))` allocates just a single pointer, correct code would be `p = (int**)malloc(size * sizeof(int*))`.

I tested your code in Visual Studio and I can't see any garbage in p[0] and p[1]. I assume it is based on how your compiler and/or operating system organizes heap. Since you didn't specify them in your question, it is hard to comment.

So you don't allocate memory for `p[1]` to `p[4]`. But you write values to there. So where do you think those values actually go? Those values are written to RAM, but it is not a memory you own for p[] array. Those two strange numbers -71290384 and -71290352 are actually values you wrote to `p[2]` and `p[4]`. (It is ff8ffbc031f0 hex and ff8ffbc03210 hex respectively, upper bit is set but that is irrelevant.) It is because when you write to `p[2]`, you actually write to memory allocated for that other local `k`. This behavior depends on concrete heap organization, so it differs on other operating systems and/or compilers.

Also, while p[2] and p[4] are accidentally written to memory allocated for other variables, it seems that by writing to unallocated p[1] and p[3] you corrupted your heap.